Individuals vs People. Is it correct to use "individuals" to refer to people of a particular type in a positive light?
individuals (sense 4): (informal, usually disapproving) a person of a particular type, especially a strange one.
I'm trying to know when I can use individuals to replace people to avoid repetition in writing. After a long time researching, I've come up with my own rule:

People is much safer to use than individuals. However, I can use individuals in one of the following two cases:

When referring to individuals as opposed to organizations, countries, etc.
When referring to a certain type of people, in which case there are often modifiers coming before or after individuals. But this is usually used in a negative light as described in sense 4 in the dictionary, which is linked above.


Then, I found these examples in the dictionary, which is not listed among examples of sense 4 though:

Like many creative individuals, she can be very bad-tempered.
The ballot papers could easily fall into the hands of an unscrupulous individual.

Now, there's a problem because obviously, the first dictionary example above is not disapproving. So, when can I use individuals to replace people? Is my below sentence correct?

In many parts of the world, ambition is often held in high regard, with individuals having ambitious goals often being praised and celebrated.
 The increasing affordability of modern transportation has allowed individuals to travel abroad more easily. (According to my rule, this is not a good use of the word because it doesn't fall into either of my rules)


Read the dictionary sub-definition again. All 3 of the example usages would be exactly as "disapproving" if we replaced individual by person. Neither of the words individual, person have any particular negative overtones in and of themselves - it's just that the former (like, say, character) isn't particularly common in informal spoken contexts anyway, being a relatively "upmarket" term. So if it is used, it's likely to be in a disparaging context purely because the speaker is calling attention to the slightly unusual way he references his subject.

The two example sentences you give obviously have a negative connotation, but that's not because of the word individual; it's because of bad-tempered and unscrupulous.

They're basically interchangeable, but the use of "individuals" gives emphasis to the people's individual nature. You'd probably refer to a "crowd of people" rather than a "crowd of individuals", since a crowd emphasizes the group nature. On the other hand, you might give an award to "the most creative individuals" on the team rather than the "most creative people", to recognize their uniqueness. As for the example sentences:

In many parts of the world, ambition is often held in high regard,
with individuals having ambitious goals often being praised and
celebrated.

This is a good use of "individuals" since these people are somewhat unique and stand out against the background. It suggests that this type of ambitious person is not overwhelmingly common.

The increasing affordability of modern transportation has allowed
individuals to travel abroad more easily.

This might be better with "people" since we are referring to trends in the group as a whole. With "individuals", it suggests that it may have gotten easier for some particular people (like rich people, for example) to travel. It may also be suggesting something about the ease of traveling solo (as an individual, as opposed to traveling with a family for example). But the sentence is probably intended to imply something about the affordability of travel for everyone in general, so "people" might be a better choice.

Thanks a lot. What do you think about the dictionary definition I gave above? Do you think the way we view these individuals, i.e. as positive or negative, matters?

I don't think "gives emphasis to the people's individual nature" is at all relevant to either of OP's cited contexts (many creative individuals, an unscrupulous individual). In both cases, the only difference is that individual belongs in a somewhat "higher register" than person/people, and deliberately using the less common term adds a "superior, dismissive" tone.

@AnIELTSLearner It is better to compare the usage of persons and people. As these are the two terms which are similar. You can get a comparative study on this website. - https://clapingo.com/blog/persons-vs-people
